# Require Administrator Password to Change Power Settings

Tags: windows-7

This is a convenience issue to help my mother-in-law's sanity :)

Her laptop set up so that the computer goes to sleep when she shuts the lid, and requires a password on wakeup. That way, when she just closes the lid, if her child sneaks in to grab the laptop from her room, she knows he can't do anything with it without the password. The problem is, her child, using a non-administrator account, can change the power setting for what happens when the lid is closed, and then she always needs to be double-checking to make sure the laptop went to sleep.

**How can I make it so that an administrator password is required to change power settings?** In the User Account Control Settings, I have it set to "Always Notify", but still no password is required for changing power settings.

Comment: Are you sure her account isn't an Administrator account? Anything UAC pops up for that requires her to hit "OK" should present as requesting a password for non-admins.

Comment: yes - i double checked that i had tested it correctly, and a password is not required for changing power settings regardless of whether or not an administrator account is currently in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to make another account, one that is not an administrator, and I do not think that it will be able to adjust power settings. I do not know for certain that this is the case.

Another alternative is that every time she closes the lid on the computer, she hits, <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. This locks the computer, and can become a rather simple habit to keep up if done every time. It would be annoying, but it is a guarantee every time.

Comment: Getting into the habit of locking your computer manually *every* time you leave any computer your logged into using SUPER+L is definitely a good habit to have.